# Why is this regex slow? Can it be faster?

Tags: .net, regex

```
re = new Regex ((.*?)someliteraltext(.*?moreliteral), RegexOptions.Singleline);
re.Match(c);
```

Note that Singleline is used, so that "." matches newline.

I run this on a chunk of text that is about 100k characters and it runs for minutes.

Can it be faster?

Comment: Do you _need_ the starting `(.*?)`?

Comment: How about rewriting this to `IndexOf`?

Comment: Or perhaps you should prefix it with `^`

Comment: What exactly is your goal with this regex? Are you just trying to determine if `someliteraltext` exists, or are you interested in capturing the text _around_ `someliteraltext`? Either way, this code can be re-written to not use a regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with the comments that the thing that's most likely slowing it down the most is that starting (.*?). If you have 1000 characters in front of the first "someliteraltext", that's already 1001 matches of that portion of the regex. @CodeInChaos' suggestion of prefixing with `^` (beginning of string) is a quick way to limit those matches. If that isn't acceptable, you'll need to explain more of what you're trying to do with the matches to get a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's slow because it requires a lot of backtracking. The article here:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/engine.html

might give you some idea of just how much work it's doing.

As @Wrikken suggested, by removing the initial "(.*?)". This capture group will capture everything from the start of the string until "someliteraltext".

Alternatively, use "IndexOf" to find "someliteraltext" and then "moreliteral" after it. That should be faster.